# Replace two different characters with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to use Regex to add a space between the parentheses and the arithmetic operators and digits.

For example, I want to replace `(+ 2 3)` with `( + 2 3 )`

I wrote this Regex, but doesn't seem to work:

```
((\(|\))[\d\w +*/-])+
```

I use Python to replace the characters in the string.

Comment: 1) Are the numbers always single digit or multiple digit numbers like 35 in `(+ 2 35)` possible? 2) is a non-regex solution acceptable?

Comment: multiple digit and regex only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "(+ 2 3)"
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?<=\()(?=[-\d+/*])|(?<=[-\d+/*])(?=\))', r' ', s)
>>> m
'( + 2 3 )'
```

Comment: Better `(?<=\()(?=[-\d+/*])|(?<=[-\d+/*)])(?=\))`

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression: `([(]+)|([)]+)`

Substitution: `\1 \2`

Result: `( + 2 3 )`

[Live Preview here](http://regex101.com/r/lI5kC8/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your requirement, but this is a possible solution:

```
re.sub(r'([()+*/-]|\w+) *', r'\1 ', s)
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fE6uB1/5)

Sample input:

```
(+1 3)
(  +  4 (* (/ 6 4)74))
(+ u(- a34    234))
```

Sample output:

```
( + 1 3 ) 
( + 4 ( * ( / 6 4 ) 74 ) ) 
( + u ( - a34 234 ) )
```

The slight problem with this solution is that there is an extra space added at the end.